# SharpDX Shader not found exception

Tags: c#, sharpdx

Hi I wanted to learn something about SharpDX,so I tried to copy some Samples and analyze the Code,but When I'm tryin to Run the Code from this sample:
https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/Direct3D11/MiniCube

I'm getting FileNotFoundException,because of Shader,but I've got Shader added to my project :|

Comment: Does your shader(.fx) file in the Solution Explorer have a property called BuildAction which is set as a "ToolkitFxc"?

Comment: @selkathguy
Yes,It has :/

Comment: When you look at the build output in Visual Studio, what is the full path it reports was not found? That is, is it looking for the .fx or .fxo file, and is it looking in the obj or bin directory?